# Swagger codegen: HV000030: No validator could be found for constraint 'javax.validation.constraints.Min' validating type 'Optional<java.lang.Integer>

Tags: java, spring-boot, swagger-codegen

I am getting the below error while using generated code server side when using minimum & maximum on integer type. If anybody some across this issue.. Please suggest..!
Thanks In Advance

swagger-codegen-maven-plugin version > 3.0.29
Spring boot version > 2.2.7.RELEASE

```
"pageSize": { "description": "Page size for returned records.", "type": "integer", "example": 50, "minimum": 1, "maximum": 100, "default": 50 }
```

[image]

Comment: Check out the [existing answers about the HV000030 error](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=HV000030), you can probably find a solution there.

Comment: Thanks @Helen. I have checkout quite a lot of these before creating this issue. This is specific to how swagger-codegen is generating objects especially for Integers with maximum & minimum openapi3 definition.